# Django, query filter not applying to prefetched data

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, prefetch

I have a table that contains the details of cards, and another table that holds the inventory data for those cards for the users.

I am trying to get the card's data and include the inventory quantities for the cards returned. I do this by adding a prefetch for the query.

However when I try to filter the prefetched data by the user id, it is still returning data for the users other than the one that is logged in.

**Code:**

```
sql_int = "CAST((REGEXP_MATCH(number, '\d+'))[1] as INTEGER)"
cards = magic_set_cards.objects.all().exclude(side='b').extra(select={'int': sql_int}) \
    .prefetch_related(Prefetch('inventoryCards', queryset=inventory_cards.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id))) \
    .values('id', 'set_id__code', 'set_id__name', 'set_id__isOnlineOnly', 'number', 'name', 'imageUri', 'hasNonFoil', 'hasFoil', 'inventoryCards__user_id', 'inventoryCards__nonfoil', 'inventoryCards__foil') \
    .order_by('-set_id__releaseDate', 'set_id__name', 'int', 'number')
```

**Data returned:**

```
{
    'id': UUID('a7ef0985-345d-4d0d-bd71-069870ce4fd6'),
    'set_id__code': 'MID',
    'set_id__name': 'Innistrad: Midnight Hunt',
    'set_id__isOnlineOnly': False,
    'number': '46',
    'name': 'Curse of Surveillance',
    'imageUri': 'https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/front/d/6/d6a5b3b2-4f27-4c97-9d87-d7bdcc06d36a.jpg?1634348722', 
    'hasNonFoil': True,
    'hasFoil': True,
    'inventoryCards__user_id': 3,
    'inventoryCards__nonfoil': 2,
    'inventoryCards__foil': 0
}, 
{
    'id': UUID('a7ef0985-345d-4d0d-bd71-069870ce4fd6'),
    'set_id__code': 'MID',
    'set_id__name': 'Innistrad: Midnight Hunt',
    'set_id__isOnlineOnly': False,
    'number': '46',
    'name': 'Curse of Surveillance',
    'imageUri': 'https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/front/d/6/d6a5b3b2-4f27-4c97-9d87-d7bdcc06d36a.jpg?1634348722', 
    'hasNonFoil': True,
    'hasFoil': True,
    'inventoryCards__user_id': 1,
    'inventoryCards__nonfoil': 0,
    'inventoryCards__foil': 1
}
...
```

As you can see from the data above, they are the same cards but it is returning the inventory data for two different users.

Please note that `'inventoryCards__user_id'` will not be returned in the final version, it is there for display purpose for this question.

Comment: IIRC using `values` alongside `prefetch_related` will actually cancel the prefetch. Try to remove it and see if it works

Comment: The seems to be the case, but how do I return the inventory data for the current user?